# Align an Object (Image) to the bottom

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Web Page with my index.html with something like this:

```
<img class="thumb" onclick="openPhoto(1);" src="img/images/campaign/1.jpg" width="710" height="533" alt="img"/>
```

What I need to do is to align an image at the bottom center of the screen, because when I open them, they actually appear in the top center of the screen.

Comment: You need to align them with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

just use css

```
.thumb
{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
width://your width accordingly;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to add that code to the index.html file?

Comment: Yep in the html file below <head> tag,<style type="text/css"> copy the code and paste here </style>..

Comment: top/right/bottom/left only work when the element is set to position:absolute

Comment: People usually put all CSS in separate file, if you are just beginning your HTML/CSS adventure, look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) for external CSS